# Using selecting data from database in PHP Dynamic image

Tags: php, image, dynamic

I have been working on a dynamic image script.The main reason I was searching for it is I want to show user info from a database.Here's my problem:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type:image/png");
    $array=array("I am a monument to all your sins", "Currently making pizza","Best before 12/7/09", "Farming Onions");
            function imagettftext_cr(&$im, $size, $angle, $x, $y, $color, $fontfile, $text)
            {
                // retrieve boundingbox
                $bbox = imagettfbbox($size, $angle, $fontfile, $text);
                // calculate deviation
                $dx = ($bbox[2]-$bbox[0])/2.0 - ($bbox[2]-$bbox[4])/2.0;         // deviation left-right
                $dy = ($bbox[3]-$bbox[1])/2.0 + ($bbox[7]-$bbox[1])/2.0;        // deviation top-bottom
                // new pivotpoint
                $px = $x-$dx;
                $py = $y-$dy;
                return imagettftext($im, $size, $angle, $px, $y, $color, $fontfile, $text);
            }

    $image = imagecreate(500,90);
    $black = imagecolorallocate($image,0,0,0);
    $grey_shade = imagecolorallocate($image,40,40,40);
    $white = imagecolorallocate($image,255,255,255);


    $text = $array[rand(0,sizeof($array)-1)];

    $otherFont = 'open.ttf';
    $font = 'open.ttf';

    $name = "erlis";
    $name = substr($name, 0, 25);    


    //BG text for Name
    while($i<10){
    imagettftext_cr($image,rand(2,40),rand(0,50),rand(10,500),rand(0,200),$grey_shade,$font,$name);
    $i++;
    }
    //BG text for saying
    while($i<10){
    imagettftext_cr($image,rand(0,40),rand(90,180),rand(100,500),rand(200,500),$grey_shade,$otherFont,$text);
    $i++;
    }
    // Main Text
    imagettftext_cr($image,35,0,250,46,$white,$font,$name);
    imagettftext_cr($image,10,0,250,76,$white,$otherFont,$text);
    imagepng($image);

    ?>
```

This part works perfectly with simple text and no mysql queryes. But when I try to initiate a mysql query..let's say `$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM serverplayers WHERE id=1");` it just breaks the image.It doesn't matter what kind of form I use but it just brakes my image.How can I implement some "fetch from the database" code? Maybe `$_GET['']` or something like that.

I need the `$name="erlis";` to be changed to a users info.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a matter of how to debug that beast.

1. Build yourself a URL that opens the image AND test it in any browser. Something like

   http :// yourserver / images?id=1 (adapt this to your needs please - was just an example)
2. Add your mysql sequence to the code
3. Uncomment your mimetype header modification like this:

   // header("Content-type:image/png");
4. run the link from step 1 in the browser -> the php/mysql debugging potentially hints you on the error
5. if you cannot see anything on the browser try 'view source code' from the browser's menu